# React Draggable property only being applied to final element in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking to add draggable list items to my DOM via JSX in react.

The expected output into the DOM should look like this:

```
<li draggable="true" style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Scenario 1</li>
<li draggable="true" style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Scenario 2</li>
<li draggable="true" style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Scenario 3</li>
```

But the actual output is:

```
<li style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Scenario 1</li>
<li style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Scenario 2</li>
<li draggable="true" style="border: 1px solid red;">Test Scenario 3</li>
```

Current code I have tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";

function LibraryItems(props) {

    const [{ isDragging }, dragRef] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: "li",
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
        }),
    }));

    
    // Declare and populate array of Library Scenarios
    const itemList = []
        
    props.items.map(item => {
        itemList.push(<li style={{border: 'red 1px solid'}} ref={dragRef}>{item.title}</li>);
    })

        
    return (
        <ul>
            {itemList}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default LibraryItems
```

Comment: You are overwriting the ref with each new `li`, I haven't used React-dnd, but I imagine they probably have a way to create multiple draggable elements without having to declare a ref for each one.

Comment: you should have a dragRef for each li you want to be draggable. In other terms an array of dragRefs given from useDrag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need a `dragRef` for each `li`, I would do something like this:

```
  const itemList = [];
  const drags = {};
  
  props.items.forEach((item) => {
    const drag = useDrag(() => ({
      type: "li",
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
      })
    }));

    const [{ isDragging }, dragRef] = drag;

    drags[item.title] = drag;

    itemList.push(
      <li style={{ border: "red 1px solid" }} ref={dragRef} key={item.title}>
        {item.title}
      </li>
    );
  });
```

If you want to check for example if a particular `li` is getting dragged you would access it via its title (they should be unique), for example for the li that has the title `"li1"`:

```
console.log(drags["li1"][0].isDragging);
```

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-joliot-60v7x?file=/src/App.js).